# C# Entity framework не дает правильные данные в дочернем процессе

Tags: c#, sql, база-данных, entity-framework

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

В отладочной информации видно что данные одинаковые, хотя у админа и пользователя токены разные в базе данных. Я сначала ищу токен в базе данных по id, затем у пользователя ищу по id диалога его токен. Проблема в том что я не могу получить действительные данные с базы данных для UserModel

Comment: `public async Task Close(long chatId)` - поправьте. СМС удаляет? Если нет, то думаю исключение внутри вашего 2-го потока выскакивает. `db` - создаёте в основном потоке или во 2-ом? Попробуйте в методе `Close` заблокировать объекты https://docs.microsoft.com/ru-ru/dotnet/csharp/language-reference/statements/lock

Comment: @User прочитайте внимательнее вопрос... => у меня в базе данных меняются параметры таблиц для пользователей и идёт удаление сообщений. Все отрабатывает хорошо за исключением admin.Support = false; в этом методе редактируется и сохраняется все кроме одного параметра. Проблем с потоками нет. И я писал что проблема в дочернем процессе, а не потоке. Дочерний процесс запускаю в один поток для теста. Если я там поставлю lock как вы предложили это не решит проблему, убрал lock из кода намеренно.

Comment: Недостаточно информации для воспроизведения. / Поддержу предложение заменить `void` на `Task`. И обязательно ждать (`await`) метод `Close`! Его название наводит на мысли, что он вызывается в конце работы приложения (процесса). И без эвейта изменения не успевают сохраниться. Кстати, `FirstOrDefault` следует заменить на `await FirstOrDefaultAsync`. Или, наоборот, использовать `SaveChanges` (без Async) и убрать `async` из сигнатуры метода.

Comment: _пару дней не могу решить_ - А что говорят логи? Какие sql-запросы генерирует EF? А выполнение по шагам в отладке что показывает?

Comment: `OrderBy(e => e.Name == chatId.ToString())` - весьма странная сортировка. И зачем она вообще нужна, если то же условие дальше в `FirstOrDefault`?

Comment: Я бы проверил отладочной печатью, что `admin` не `null` и `admin.Support` не `null`. А то может просто не попадает вообще на ту строку кода. И да, всё-таки `db` где берётся и как ещё используется?

Comment: @CrazyElf что то вроде if(admin != null) ?  Но по идее эти данные у меня не могут быть null так как код вызывается когда в бд записи их уже есть

Comment: @AlexanderPetrov в дебагере не могу проверить что и как показывает, так как в основном процессе все работает, а в другом который запускаю не могу вернуть данные с бд. Поменял код. Вечером в вопросе обновлю.

Comment: Обновил вопрос и код, чтобы понятнее было

Comment: "Но по идее эти данные у меня не могут быть null", ну так и код у вас по идее должен работать без проблем. Вы должны всё проверять через отладочную печать. Дебаггер не всегда корректно работает, лучше везде что-то печатать или в лог писать, чтобы точно знать, куда ветвление пошло и какие были значения.

Comment: @CrazyElf вывел все данные связанные с получением данным, все выводит что нужно, кроме токена. Токен выводит такой же как у администратора....

Comment: Если я выключаю дочерний процесс, то токен с бд берется нужный.  Но при работае дочернего процесса, я не могу получить верный токен

Comment: А вот это `user!.Dialog` - это что, это откуда? Может там проблема?

Comment: @CrazyElf user!.Dialog это id диалога из AdminModel оно равно UserId пользователя, тем самым с бд возвращаю пользователя и беру его токен

Answer (score 0):

Решение проблемы с выдачей не верных, как выяснилось старых данных через контекст Entinty.
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Я использовал контекст передавая его везде через конструктор, ставил lock где нужно для блокировки потоков, это работало в главном - 1 процессе. Но у меня мультипроцессорная программа, и при данном подходе в других процессах я считывал старый не обновленный контекст.
В моем ситуации мне помогла следующее.

```
using(var context = new DataContext()
{
var user = context.Users.FirstOrDefault(x => x.UserId == ID);
}

Создаем новый контекст и получаем актуальные данные
```

Comment: А, это старые добрые грабли, ага